# OrchardCMS Shape tracing not showing up for custom theme

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm creating a custom theme for my new Orchard site. The shape tracing module is incredibly useful, but for some reason it isn't rendering in my custom theme. I'm not sure what I might be missing to get it to appear.

When I set my site to use the theme TheThemeMachine, it appears just fine at the bottom of the page. When I compare the rendered source from the TheThemeMaching and my custom theme, I see all the CSS & JS references in the head for the shape tracing module. However when I scroll to the bottom of the source of my custom theme, I don't see all the script blogs with the JSON objects. I just see a lot of empty script "shape-tracing-wrapper" blocks.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a zone named Tail in your document.cshtml. Compare your theme's version with the one in Core/Shapes/Views.

Comment: Bingo... that was it. I had copied the TheThemeMachine but added a document.cshtml but didn't add a Tail. Thanks!

Comment: The other challenge I was running into was that I was also adding a 2nd reference to the jQuery library. Only one can be on the page so I removed mine and just used the jQuery module.